# Wrong IP when Connecting to strongSwan Server

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec

I set up a strongSwan server and I want to test connectivity.  I added my username and password, the ca-cert.pem and re-started strongswan on the client.  `service strongswan status` shows lots of `sending keep alive` messages and that seems good right?

But when I check my IP address it still shows the default, non-VPN connection.

I tried `ip route show` but it only has me `eth0` interface.  I'm used to OpenVPN so I expected a `tun` device or `ppp` I could use to `ip route` create a new route.  What am I missing?

Comment: You might want to read the [introduction to strongSwan](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IntroductionTostrongSwan) document on the strongSwan wiki plus maybe [HelpRequests](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/HelpRequests) as that provides some additional useful links/information.

Comment: @ecdsa Yes thank you.  I was so into the "Installation" and "Configuratoin" docs I completely forgot the wiki.